# How to use apply family functions on an array and a matrix instead of a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

Is there a way to use apply like functions instead of the for loop in the code below?

```
a <- array(rnorm(100,0,1), c(10, 5, 2)) ; a
b <- matrix(rnorm(20,0,1), 10, 2) ; b 

m <- matrix(NA, 10, 2) ; m
for (i in 1:2){ m[,i] <- fitted(lm(b[,i]~a[,,i])) }
m
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply`/`lapply` here :

```
m1 <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(b)), function(i) fitted(lm(b[,i]~a[,,i])))
```

`seq_len(ncol(b))` creates a sequence from `1:ncol(b)` which is similar to `1:2` in your `for` loop and the code inside `for` loop and `sapply` remains the same.